# Orientation problem on (9930)  blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I set orientation as portrait to my app.

When i check on os 6 and os 5 simulator, no problem.

But in os 7-(9930), my app display as landscape mode.

How do check and correct it.

Pls help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a Bold, meaning that its width is greater than its height which makes its portait view a landscape; anyway, you can force it to behave normal with:
net.rim.device.api.ui.Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(net.rim.device.api.lcdui.control.DirectionControl.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to make this for all devices

```
UiEngineInstance _ue = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();
if (Display.getWidth() == 640 && Display.getHeight() == 480) 
   _ue.setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_LANDSCAPE);
else 
   _ue.setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes, but it does not look good with constants like that...